# How to convert sequentially emitted data to a single array

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

So, I am using ngrx store for getting data. Once I select the property I want from the store, after then I subscribed it to get observable stream.
My data contains array of object. So in this array of objects, I have to do some modifications in some properties of each objects.

So for that I converted my array of objects into sequential observable by using 'from()' operator of rxjs library and then assign this into new Observable object. With this new Observable object, I applied map function for doing modification and at the end again returned a  new Observable object.
Till this step everything is working fine.
Problem occurs, when I am subscribing to this new modified observable object it is emitting values sequentially not the whole array of objects.
But I want modified array of objects.

```
this.statusObj = this.store.select(s => s.userStore.data);
this.statusObj.subscribe(rslt => {
    this.usrArr = rslt;
})

this.newstatusObj = from(this.usrArr);
this.newstatusObj2 = this.newstatusObj
    .pipe(map(() => {
        //////some modifications
        return
    }))

this.newstatusObj2.subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val);  //this line is emitting sequential values..but i want array of objects
})
```

Comment: What is the value of usrArr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `.from()`, that will convert your data to multiple emissions based on your array. Since your store already gives you an observable which contains your data to modify, simply use `.map()` to modify them, like this:

```
this.store.select(s => s.userStore.data)
    .pipe(map((rslt)=>{
        //DO YOUR MODIFICATION HERE.
    }))
    .subscribe(val=>{
        console.log(val) // now your data is in array of objects
    })
```